# Add label to Chart Point containing third Column Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, datatable

I am filling an ASP:Chart with values from a DataTable to get a simple Column Chart. So far so good. Now I wanted to add to each point a label that displays the value comming from a third column of my DataTable.

I am doing the following, but each point is labeled with the same value - according to the value of the last row of the DataTable. How can I achieve that each point is labeled correctly?

```
    Series series = Chart1.Series["Series1"];

    foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
    {
        string week = row["Week"].ToString();
        string OTD = row["OTD"].ToString();
        string RMA = row["RMA"].ToString();
        int YVal = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(OTD), 0));
        series.Points.AddXY(week, YVal);
        series.Label = RMA;
    }
```

---

OK, I got it. One has to address the points in the same loop:

```
series.Points[t.Rows.IndexOf(row)].Label = RMA;
```

Comment: You have only one Series object so the last row of the Datatable (from the foreach loop) is being inserted into the Series

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If I add a second series I can add a label that displays the value of the third column of my DataTable? How would that be?

Comment: I meant the if you had List<Series> you can have a different label value for each row of the DataTable.  You only have one Series so when your for loop ends the value of RMA is the value of the last row of the DataTable.

Comment: Thank you, jdweng. Probably I didn't explain myself too clear. I managed to achieve what I wanted and updated my question